# watchCollection on property containing a dot

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a property whose name contains a dot (.). I'm aware this is uncommon, but the reason is that these are built automatically and you may see it as key1.key2.

Now the watchCollection on this property "key1.key2" fails, as it is interpreted as property key2 of object key1. The first parameter of Angular watchCollection  has to be an expression. We tried as well:

```
$scope.$watchCollection ('["key1.key2"]', ...);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: have you tried using a parser to transform those keys from k.k to k_k and then use them in js? and then before send the data back transform it again into k.k ?

Comment: this would work for sure... as in this case it would just be a "normal" property name... but I was wondering if there was a solution in my use case... as even if "uncommon", you may use dotted property in js.

Comment: oh yes there are ways, you can take any of the responses bellow and they will work, but i feels more natural just to parse and transform. also more readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$scope.$watchCollection ('this["key1.key2"]', ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

If collection defined like this:

```
$scope['key1.key2'] = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
```

then

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
  return $scope['key1.key2'];
}, function(newCollection) {
  console.log(newCollection);
});
```

see *Details* for *obj* parameter for [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection). It can be or string or function